# Using a Sheet tab as a button for expanding/collapsing a set of tabs

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using the following code (from the [Experts Exchange site](http://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/1685/Excel-Using-a-Sheet-Tab-as-a-Button-for-Expanding-Collapsing-Supplementary-Sheets.html)):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
If ShowHide.Name = "Show My Guts" Then
    'Make all sheets visible
    For Each sheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        sheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Next sheet
    'Change the sheet name to the "Collapse" name you want
    ShowHide.Name = "Hide My Guts"
    'Pick a sheet to display after the once hidden sheets are expanded
    Sheet4.Activate
Else
    'Hide all sheets except the ones you want to keep visible
    For Each sheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If (sheet.Name <> Results.Name And sheet.Name <> Run.Name And sheet.Name <> ShowHide.Name) Then
           sheet.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
        End If
    Next sheet
    'Change the sheet name to the "Expand" name you want
    ShowHide.Name = "Show My Guts"
    'Pick a sheet to display after the sheets to be hidden are collapsed
    Run.Activate
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I've renamed the "Show My Guts" name to my worksheet name and selected a different sheet to activate by modifying the "Sheet4.Activate" option but when saving the macro, a dialog pops up saying "runtime error 424 Object required" and when I click "debug" on the dialog, the line

```
If ShowHide.Name = "Show My Guts" Then
```

is highlighted.

I tried using the code as is without any modofication and it still gives me the same error.

What is wrong in the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ShowHide is the "vba name" he gave to the sheet.
There is a difference between the "technical name" and the "display name"

A little screenshot speek more than words :
[image: Difference between technical name and display name]

So in VBA you have to rename the sheet you want to "ShowHide" as "ShowHide" or you name it differently and change the ShowHide in the VBA code by your new choice

**update:** you have to modify this in your code

```
' ShowHide to rename (or rename your sheet under vba with ShowHide)
If ShowHide.Name = "Show My Guts" Then
    ...
    ' ShowHide to rename (or rename your sheet under vba with ShowHide)
    ShowHide.Name = "Hide My Guts"
Else
    For Each sheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        ' ShowHide to rename (or rename your sheet under vba with ShowHide)
        If (sheet.Name <> Results.Name And sheet.Name <> Run.Name And sheet.Name <> ShowHide.Name) Then
            ...
        End If
    Next sheet
    ' ShowHide to rename (or rename your sheet under vba with ShowHide)
    ShowHide.Name = "Show My Guts"
    ...
End If
```

Comment: If I correctly understand, the following lines need to be modified by replacing the appropriate sheet names: 
   
`If ShowHide.Name = "Show My Guts" Then` , 

`ShowHide.Name = "Hide My Guts" ` ,

`Sheet4.Activate  `,

`If (sheet.Name <> Results.Name And sheet.Name <> Run.Name And sheet.Name <> ShowHide.Name) Then  `,

`ShowHide.Name = "Show My Guts"  `,

`Run.Activate`   ?

Comment: Yes this is it. I update the answer to add the lines you have to correct